# Intellij Rest Service Project - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, rest, intellij-idea, jersey, jax-rs

I created a Restful Web Service project on Intelli jidea with the default HelloWorld sample that was created by Ide.

```
 package example;
 import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
 import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;

 /**
  * Created by UNAL on 12.07.2016.
  */
 // The Java class will be hosted at the URI path "/helloworld"
 @Path("/helloworld")
 public class HelloWorld {
     // The Java method will process HTTP GET requests
     @GET
     // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media type "text/plain"
     @Produces("text/plain")
     public String getClichedMessage() {
         // Return some cliched textual content
         return "Hello World";
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:9998/");
         server.start();

         System.out.println("Server running");
         System.out.println("Visit: http://localhost:9998/helloworld");
         System.out.println("Hit return to stop...");
         System.in.read();
         System.out.println("Stopping server");
         server.stop(0);
         System.out.println("Server stopped");
     }
 }
```

When i try to run it i got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 256
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner$1.f(JarFileScanner.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:71)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.FilesScanner.scan(FilesScanner.java:83)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.FilesScanner.scan(FilesScanner.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig.init(ClasspathResourceConfig.java:119)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig.<init>(ClasspathResourceConfig.java:101)
at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:263)
at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:246)
at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:117)
at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:92)
at example.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I already tried version 2.2, 1.2 and 1.0 of Jersey libraries.
Jdk 1.8.0_91

Comment: please use the newer jersey libraries and post the new code. this is really old one. i dont think it has sth to do with jidea.

Comment: new versions of jersey doesn't contain HttpServerFactory class. Do you know how can we generate the code with the latest Jersey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to be a problem with java 8. had the same exception and when i changed java version to use my JDK 7, it stopped complaining.

Comment: i have installed latest version of Intellij Idea now. Result is same. I'll try us JDK 7 as you said.

Comment: did the same thing as you did and this worked for me. same error with JDK 8, error gone with JDK 7.

Comment: I have tried few minutes ago and yes, its working now. i changed version of jersey as 1.12, and also changed to jdk as 7. Now its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried latest version of jersey (1.19.4) and it works with JDK 8.
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version> 
</dependency>
```